# Unfindable SQLite Syntax Error

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying out statements for creating a database, and after 10 entities without any issues I ran into this error

> Error: Near line 83: near "Transaction": syntax error

The first line is line 83 with it's context of creating a table

```
CREATE TABLE Transaction (
TransactionID INTEGER,
AccountID INTEGER REFERENCES User (AccountID),
ItemID INTEGER REFERENCES Item (ItemID),
Method STRING,
Price INTEGER,
TransactionDate DATE,
PRIMARY KEY (TransactionID)
);
```

Now I can't seem to find the issue, and suggestion's of something with ASCII using the wrong space couldn't be solved by writing the same thing again manually.

I haven't even gotten around to checking the integrity of my foreign keys, and it's not working. Hopefully somebody could provide some insight on what I'm missing.

Comment: `Transaction` might be a reserved word.  See here -- http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html

Comment: Isn't Transaction a reserved word? Try a different table name

Comment: ^^ It _is_ reserved. Double quote it or choose a different name.

Comment: Thank you all so much! I'll add an answer to the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Transaction` is one of the reserved names in SQLite. For a full list see [here.](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html)

Ways to solve this issue are:

- Change the Table name to a word that isn't reserved.

**or**

- Quote the reserved name by using one of [these](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) 4 listed quote marks

  - 'keyword'
  - "keyword"
  - [keyword]
  - `keyword`