# CASE WHEN query in room database

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

**CASE WHEN query in room database **

> I have three type case where I want to fire three different condition

1. case 1 : check date and return result
2. case 2: check date and end_date & neverends=1 return result
3. case 3 : checK DATE and return result

> below is the query

```
  @Query(
    "select * FROM `Task` WHERE task_type =(CASE  WHEN ${Constant.REPEAT_TYPE.ONETIME} THEN task_start_date=:todayDate END DESC," +
            "CASE type WHEN ${Constant.REPEAT_TYPE.REPEAT} THEN task_start_date=:todayDate OR task_never_end=1 OR task_end_date >=:todayDate END DESC," +
            "CASE type WHEN ${Constant.REPEAT_TYPE.LOCATION} THEN task_start_date=:todayDate END DESC)"
)
```

**Error Log**

```
    error: mismatched input 'DESC' expecting {')', ',', '=', '*', '+', '-', '||', '/', '%', '<<', '>>', '&', '|', '<', '<=', '>', '>=', '==', '!=', '<>', K_AND, K_BETWEEN, K_COLLATE, K_GLOB, K_IN, K_IS, K_ISNULL, K_LIKE, K_MATCH, K_NOT, K_NOTNULL, K_OR, K_REGEXP}
    public abstract java.util.List<com.example.todolist.database.entity.Task> getTodassyTask(long todayDate);
                                                                              ^
  extraneous input 'DESC' expecting {<EOF>, ';', K_ALTER, K_ANALYZE, K_ATTACH, K_BEGIN, K_COMMIT, K_CREATE, K_DELETE, K_DETACH, K_DROP, K_END, K_EXPLAIN, K_INSERT, K_PRAGMA, K_REINDEX, K_RELEASE, K_REPLACE, K_ROLLBACK, K_SAVEPOINT, K_SELECT, K_UPDATE, K_VACUUM, K_VALUES, K_WITH, UNEXPECTED_CHAR}
  extraneous input 'DESC' expecting {<EOF>, ';', K_ALTER, K_ANALYZE, K_ATTACH, K_BEGIN, K_COMMIT, K_CREATE, K_DELETE, K_DETACH, K_DROP, K_END, K_EXPLAIN, K_INSERT, K_PRAGMA, K_REINDEX, K_RELEASE, K_REPLACE, K_ROLLBACK, K_SAVEPOINT, K_SELECT, K_UPDATE, K_VACUUM, K_VALUES, K_WITH, UNEXPECTED_CHAR}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unfindable SQLite Syntax Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28891535/unfindable-sqlite-syntax-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DESC` is short for DESCENDING, it's use is in an `ORDER BY` clause. You do not have an `ORDER BY` clause. Hence, it saying it is expecting something before DESC.

If the returned column is to be called DESC then enclose it in ``  e.g.

```
`DESC`
```

- not the best name for a column though

Comment: Hi ! can u help me here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73893183/matching-multiple-title-in-single-query-using-like-keyword