# How do you save a List<> as a column in a table in room?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I am building an app in which I have a Room entity that one of its columns is supposed to hold a List.

**What is the best approach for doing this in an app that uses Flow, Coroutines and Room**?

I tried serializing with Jackson (turning the List to a long json String and then bring it back to a List when fetched) but I am not sure if this is the correct approach.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best approach for doing this in an app that uses Flow, Coroutines and Room?

This is very much open to opinion.

From a database perspective the approach would be to have any list as a table and thus

- reducing the JSON bloat and thus reducing efficiency,
- reduce duplication and thus be more likely to conform to normalisation
- not potentially introducing complexities and even greater inefficiencies *(e.g. not mentioned in the answer below but wild-character as the first character must do a full table scan)*

  - perhaps consider this question and answer [matching multiple title in single query using like keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73893183/matching-multiple-title-in-single-query-using-like-keyword) where if the table per list approach were taken then a simple `SELECT * FROM task WHERE task_tags IN(:taglist)` could do the same

From a coding point of view at first the coding is simpler when embedding JSON as the complex code is within the JSON libraries.